# Microsoft Sync Framework - Performance and scalability

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, scalability, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to use Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 on a SQL Server database. There will be a  high number of concurrent end users, synchronizing with a central database server.

Further specifications are:

- 1500 concurrent clients connect to 1 central database server

  - Client are using MS SQL Server Express 2008 R2
  - Server is using MS SQL Server Enterprise 2008 R2
- Short sync intervals (around 5 minutes)
- Database size will be 5 GB
- A webservice will be used as server-side SyncProvider

Does anyone have experience with Sync Framework environments similar to this?

- Is it possible?
- What is important to take into account when implementing this?
- What are the physical limits that I can expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

some things to keep in mind:

1. No. of scopes - you might want to keep a 1-to-1 scope ratio for client-to-server instead of 1500 client scopes against one server scope. this isolates the sync knowledge of each client from one another, you may even drop and recreate a client scope without affecting other scopes. sync knowledge will be much compact as well.
2. Scope definition - dont dump all tables in one scope. different tables have different characteristics (e.g., download only, read-only, less frequent update, frequently updated, etc...). group tables based on their characteristics.
3. Batching - if the changes are small, dont batch. you incur performance overhead in batching since the batching has to write files and later on, it has to reconstitute the change dataset from the files.
4. Metadata Cleanup - setup metadata retention and metadata cleanup process. this should reduce the sync metadata (rows in the tracking tables and the sync knowledge).
5. WCF config -watch out for your WCF config entries such as timeout, message size, etc... be aware of this issue as well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2567595

EDIT:

Also, have a look at other Scope considerations here: [Sync Framework Scope and SQL Azure Data Sync Dataset Considerations](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/sync-framework-scope-and-sql-azure-data-sync-dataset-considerations/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already take into account of your points 2, 3 and 5. But I am curious about your first point. Can you explain it a little bit further what you mean with 1-to-1 scope? We encounter a lot of problems (for example 100% conflicts) if we creates multiple scopes pointing to the same table.

Comment: normally, you would provision a scope on the server and then use getdescriptionforscope and apply that to a client. so in most cases, you only have one scope in the server (one row in the scope_info table) and multiple client scopes synching against it. the scope keeps track of the replica Ids of all scopes inside the sync knowledge so in your case, your replica key map will be 1501 mappings (1500 client Ids plus server id). also, if you want to modify the scope for a client, you cant just modify the server scope because the other 1499 clients are sharing the same scope on the server.

Comment: am not sure how you end up having 100% conflicts for having multiple scope, how are you initializing your clients? are you copying one master copy of database over to each client?

Comment: You described exact the situation we have. We have one server scope and multiple clients syncing against it. We also see a growing knowledge server side (which is OK because you need this knowledge) and also client side (which we dont want). What I see now is that you want to have: 1500 scopes server side and 1 scope client side (With respect to point 2 of your answer, so scopedefinitions.count*clients.count == serverside-scopes.count and scopedefinitions.count == clientside-scopes.count). Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: The situation which causes 100% conflicts:
T1 is defined in S1 and S2. If you provision S1 and S2 both on server and on all clients, you get a horrable situation. S1 is conflicting with S2 client side and uploads all records to the server, which causes conflicts because all clients are doing this. Now (If my explaination in my previous comment is correct) I see where this went wrong and what we need to do.

Comment: yes, each client having their corresponding scope in the server.

Comment: you have conflicts because you have overlapping scopes...this is a documented behaviour. the knowledge of S1 and S2 are totally independent. if you sync S1, it downloads changes and updates its knowledge to record the changes it got. S2 however has no idea of those changes, so when it syncs, it sends its knowledge to the server and its knowledge will not have the changes received by S1, so the server sends the changes again, thus causing the conflicts...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10049/discussion-between-hwcverwe-and-junet)

Answer (score 0):

The sample provided here : http://www.rajneeshnoonia.com/blog/2012/03/n-tier-sync-framework/

Is some thing close to your requirements

1:1 scope defined => we defined template and configure scope for each client based on this template.In this senerio T1 is defined in S1 and S2 however filters are used to identify row level records for each scope.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable link. Nice blogpost you wrote :)