# What are the factors need to be taken into consideration while using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

Right now we have got an developed application for maintenance and one of the major issue is the Sync Time.

It's almost taking 50 to 60 secs to synchronize between the local CE database and remote SQL Server.

It takes less than 12secs while synchronizing the same local CE database with local SQL Server.

This points that location of server is definitely ruling the grounds but again what are the other factors need to be evaluated while using [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx).

Is there any standards specified as such how many scopes and how to use provisioning efficently.

Comment: Adding another useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106978/microsoft-sync-framework-performance-and-scalability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to post here, so posting a link instead : [Sync Framework Scope and SQL Azure Data Sync Dataset Considerations](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/sync-framework-scope-and-sql-azure-data-sync-dataset-considerations/)

Other things you can look at are batching and metadata clean up.

Note that Sync Framework is just like any other database app, so stuff like proper indexing also is a plus.